# iOS Swift: LaunchScreen doesn't show image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, launcher

Evening, my **launch screen** doesn't show the new images that I add in the assets. It displays only a black screen... Like if the image view isn't there.

This happen only in my device, while in the simulator they are visible.
The old images are all displayed properly.

I've tried to delete the app and install it agains but still I have the problem.

I've tired with jpgs pngs and vector.

Any tip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you were having different images then you change it to something else, the device cache the old launch screen and doesn't show your new images, just try to restart the device then reinstall, it will show your new images

Comment: Restarting the simulator worked for me. `Hardware -> Restart`.

Comment: This answer really save my life, don't know why device only cache the launch screen but not other changed icons for example. Restart iPhone resolve the problem.